# count the number of three way conversations in a group chat dataset using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I wanted to count the number of three way conversations that have occured in a dataset.
A chat `group_x` can consist of multiple members.

What is a three way conversation?

1. 1st way - `red`_x sends a message in the group_x.
2. 2nd way - `green`_x replies in the same group_x.
3. 3rd way - `red`_x sends a reply in the same group_x.

This can be called a three way conversation.

The sequence has to be exactly red_#, green_#, red_#.

What is touchpoint?

1. Touchpoint 1 - red_x's first message.
2. Touchpoint 2 - green_x's first message.
3. Touchpoint 3 - red_x's second message.

Code to easily generate a sample dataset I'm working with.

```py
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp

t1_df = pd.DataFrame({'from_red': [True, False, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, False, True], 
              'sent_time': [Timestamp('2021-05-01 06:26:00'), Timestamp('2021-05-04 10:35:00'), Timestamp('2021-05-07 12:16:00'), Timestamp('2021-05-07 12:16:00'), Timestamp('2021-05-09 13:39:00'), Timestamp('2021-05-11 10:02:00'), Timestamp('2021-05-12 13:10:00'), Timestamp('2021-05-12 13:10:00'), Timestamp('2021-05-13 09:46:00'), Timestamp('2021-05-13 22:30:00'), Timestamp('2021-05-14 14:14:00'), Timestamp('2021-05-14 17:08:00'), Timestamp('2021-06-01 09:22:00'), Timestamp('2021-06-01 21:26:00'), Timestamp('2021-06-03 20:19:00'), Timestamp('2021-06-03 20:19:00'), Timestamp('2021-06-09 07:24:00'), Timestamp('2021-05-01 06:44:00'), Timestamp('2021-05-01 08:01:00'), Timestamp('2021-05-01 08:09:00')], 
              'w_uid': ['w_000001', 'w_112681', 'w_002516', 'w_002514', 'w_004073', 'w_005349', 'w_006803', 'w_006804', 'w_008454', 'w_009373', 'w_010063', 'w_010957', 'w_066840', 'w_071471', 'w_081446', 'w_081445', 'w_106472', 'w_000002', 'w_111906', 'w_000003'], 
              'user_id': ['red_00001', 'green_0263', 'red_01071', 'red_01071', 'red_01552', 'red_01552', 'red_02282', 'red_02282', 'red_02600', 'red_02854', 'red_02854', 'red_02600', 'red_00001', 'red_09935', 'red_10592', 'red_10592', 'red_12292', 'red_00002', 'green_0001', 'red_00003'], 
              'group_id': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], 
              'touchpoint': [1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1]}, 
                     columns = ['from_red', 'sent_time', 'w_uid', 'user_id', 'group_id', 'touchpoint'])

t1_df['sent_time'] = pd.to_datetime(t1_df['sent_time'], format = "%d-%m-%Y")
t1_df
```

The dataset looks like this:

| from_red | sent_time | w_uid | user_id | group_id | touchpoint |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| True | 2021-05-01 06:26:00 | w_000001 | red_00001 | 0 | 1 |
| False | 2021-05-04 10:35:00 | w_112681 | green_0263 | 0 | 2 |
| True | 2021-05-07 12:16:00 | w_002516 | red_01071 | 0 | 1 |
| True | 2021-05-07 12:16:00 | w_002514 | red_01071 | 0 | 3 |
| True | 2021-05-09 13:39:00 | w_004073 | red_01552 | 0 | 1 |
| True | 2021-05-11 10:02:00 | w_005349 | red_01552 | 0 | 3 |
| True | 2021-05-12 13:10:00 | w_006803 | red_02282 | 0 | 1 |
| True | 2021-05-12 13:10:00 | w_006804 | red_02282 | 0 | 3 |
| True | 2021-05-13 09:46:00 | w_008454 | red_02600 | 0 | 1 |
| True | 2021-05-13 22:30:00 | w_009373 | red_02854 | 0 | 1 |
| True | 2021-05-14 14:14:00 | w_010063 | red_02854 | 0 | 3 |
| True | 2021-05-14 17:08:00 | w_010957 | red_02600 | 0 | 3 |
| True | 2021-06-01 09:22:00 | w_066840 | red_00001 | 0 | 3 |
| True | 2021-06-01 21:26:00 | w_071471 | red_09935 | 0 | 1 |
| True | 2021-06-03 20:19:00 | w_081446 | red_10592 | 0 | 1 |
| True | 2021-06-03 20:19:00 | w_081445 | red_10592 | 0 | 3 |
| True | 2021-06-09 07:24:00 | w_106472 | red_12292 | 0 | 1 |
| True | 2021-05-01 06:44:00 | w_000002 | red_00002 | 1 | 1 |
| False | 2021-05-01 08:01:00 | w_111906 | green_0001 | 1 | 2 |
| True | 2021-05-01 08:09:00 | w_000003 | red_00003 | 1 | 1 |

Here is what I have tried, but the query is taking too long. Is there a faster way to achieve the same?

```py
test_df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(len(t1_df['sent_time'])-1):
    if t1_df.query(f"group_id == {i}")['from_red'].nunique() == 2:
        y = t1_df.query(f"group_id == {i} & touchpoint == 2").loc[:, ['sent_time']].values[0][0]
        x = t1_df.query(f"group_id == {i} & sent_time > @y & (touchpoint == 3)").sort_values('sent_time')
        test_df = pd.concat([test_df, x])
        test_df.merge(x, how = "outer")
        
    else:
        pass

test_df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it's not clear how you define the "three way conversation". Within on group, if you have the `input` messages what option(s) do you consider as "three way conversation"? There are several options:

```
Input  : red_0, red_2, green_0, red_1, red_0, red_2, red_1
Option1:        red_2, green_0, red_1
Option2: red_0,        green_0,        red_0
   +   :        red_2, green_0,               red_2
```

and many more. Your code example returns the second msg of a user when sent after green:

```
OptionX:               green_0,         red_0
   +   :               green_0,               red_2
   +   :               green_0,                      red_1
```

without keeping track if some red user sent a msg before green. Another question is, what happens if green is sending multiple times within one group.

```
Input  : red_0, red_2, green_0, green_0, red_1, red_0, green_1, red_1
```

Based on your description "The sequence has to be exactly `red_#, green_#, red_#`." I guess, Option1 is what you are looking for and maybe that it's even independent from the color: `color0_#, color1_#, color0_#`. Correct me if I'm wrong ;).

## Prepare the DataFrame

To get the operation more generic, I would first prepare the DataFrame, e.g. extract the color of the user and get a integer represenation for the color

```py
# extract the user color and id
t1_df[['color', 'id']] = t1_df.pop('user_id').str.split('_', expand=True)
# get the dtypes right, also it is not needed here
t1_df.id = t1_df.id.astype(int)
t1_df.color = t1_df.color.astype('category')
# get color as intager
t1_df['color_as_int'] =pd.factorize(t1_df.color)[0]
```

## Detect the sequence `color0_#, color1_#, color0_#`

```py
# a three way conversation is where color_as_int is [...,a,b,a,...]
# expressed as difference it's color_as_int.diff() is [...,c,-c,...]
# get the difference with tracking the group, therefore first sort
t1_df.sort_values(['group_id', 'sent_time'], inplace=True)
d_color = t1_df.groupby(['group_id']).color_as_int.diff()
m = (d_color != 0) & (d_color == -d_color.shift(-1))  # detect [...,c,-c,...]
# count up for each three way conversation
m[m] = m[m].cumsum()
m = m.astype(int)

# get the labels for the dataframe [...,a,b,a,...]
t1_df['three_way_conversation'] = m + m.shift(1, fill_value=0) + m.shift(-1, fill_value=0)
```

which returns and works for any color

```py
columns = ['sent_time', 'group_id', 'color', 'id', 'touchpoint']
print(t1_df.loc[t1_df['three_way_conversation']>0, columns])

             sent_time  group_id  color    id  touchpoint
0  2021-05-01 06:26:00         0    red     1           1
1  2021-05-04 10:35:00         0  green   263           2
2  2021-05-07 12:16:00         0    red  1071           1
17 2021-05-01 06:44:00         1    red     2           1
18 2021-05-01 08:01:00         1  green     1           2
19 2021-05-01 08:09:00         1    red     3           1
```

### Bonus

with the DataFrame preparation you can easily count the msg per color or user within a group or get the first and last time of a msg from a color or user. `cumcount` is faster as `count` and `pd.merg()` afterwards.

```py
t1_df['color_msg_count'] = t1_df.groupby(['group_id', 'color']).cumcount() + 1
t1_df['user_msg_count'] = t1_df.groupby(['group_id', 'color', 'id']).cumcount() + 1

t1_df['user_sent_time_min'] = t1_df.sort_values('sent_time').groupby(['group_id', 'color', 'id']).sent_time.cummin()
t1_df['user_sent_time_max'] = t1_df.sort_values('sent_time', ascending=False).groupby(['group_id', 'color', 'id']).sent_time.cummax()
```

Comment: Actually, I wanted Option2: `red_0`, `green_0, `red_0` to be counted as 3-way conversation. `red_1`, `green_0, `red_1` should also be counted and so-on.

Comment: Ok, so you want that red is from the same user right? This adds another constrain. I’m not sure, if you can get this out of the box with groupby avoiding slow python loops. But you can reduce the loops n dramatically, with a combination. E.g first detect wich groups have red and green msg and so. And only loop over the sub samples, where you can again use groubpy.

Comment: And if you want to get loops extremely fast, have a look at numba or similar.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `.groupby` to act on the whole dataset at once.

```py
# Get first occurence of sent_time for each group if touchpoint==2
groups = t1_df[t1_df['touchpoint']==2].groupby('group_id')['sent_time'].first()

# Reformat dataframe
groups = groups.reset_index().rename(columns={'sent_time':'first_time'})

# Add these times to dataframe by using 'group_id' as the lookup column
t1_df = t1_df.merge(groups)


# Apply remaining conditional flags
condition = t1_df['sent_time'] > t1_df['first_time']
condition &= t1_df['touchpoint'] == 3

test_df = t1_df[condition].drop('first_time', axis=1)

# Sort by groups, then by sent_times in each group
test_df = test_df.sort_values(['group_id','sent_time'])

# Cleanup
t1_df = t1_df.drop('first_time', axis=1)
```

**Benchmarking**

This method runs in about `0.52 seconds` for a dataframe with 1 million rows (simply repeating the original dataframe and incrementing the `group_id`).